# getting error right after successful login to odoo

Tags: python, nginx, runtime-error, odoo, odoo-15

**Note:** This issue occurs only when accessing odoo via nginx proxy.

When accessed directly odoo works fine.

Right after i login to odoo i get the below error as copied onto the clipboard:

[image]

```
UncaughtClientError > SyntaxError
Uncaught Javascript Error > Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (https://vidatest.xyz/web/assets/108-9a7b0d7/web.assets_backend.min.js:585:55)
```

I'm on centos 7/8 odoo version 15

```
root@ip-172-31-42-237:/var/log# systemctl status odoo
● odoo.service - Odoo15
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/odoo.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-04-06 10:26:20 UTC; 6min ago
   Main PID: 420828 (python3)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 4623)
     Memory: 138.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/odoo.service
             └─420828 /opt/odoo/odoo-venv/bin/python3 /opt/odoo/odoo/odoo-bin -c /etc/odoo.conf -u vida_product
```

Below is the syslog that seems to suggest all is good.

```
Apr  6 10:28:43 ip-172-31-42-237 odoo[420828]: 2022-04-06 10:28:43,520 420828 INFO vida odoo.addons.base.models.res_users: Login successful for db:vida login:saif.kamaal@digiklug.com from 127.0.0.1
Apr  6 10:28:43 ip-172-31-42-237 odoo[420828]: 2022-04-06 10:28:43,538 420828 INFO vida werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2022 10:28:43] "POST /web/login HTTP/1.0" 303 - 16 0.023 0.072
Apr  6 10:28:43 ip-172-31-42-237 odoo[420828]: 2022-04-06 10:28:43,677 420828 INFO vida werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2022 10:28:43] "GET /web HTTP/1.0" 200 - 17 0.007 0.086
Apr  6 10:28:44 ip-172-31-42-237 odoo[420828]: 2022-04-06 10:28:44,170 420828 INFO vida werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2022 10:28:44] "POST /web/dataset/call_kw/res.users/systray_get_activities HTTP/1.0" 200 - 2 0.001 0.005
Apr  6 10:28:44 ip-172-31-42-237 odoo[420828]: 2022-04-06 10:28:44,178 420828 INFO vida werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2022 10:28:44] "GET /web/image?model=res.users&field=avatar_128&id=2 HTTP/1.0" 304 - 5 0.003 0.010
Apr  6 10:28:44 ip-172-31-42-237 odoo[420828]: 2022-04-06 10:28:44,228 420828 INFO vida werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2022 10:28:44] "POST /web/action/load HTTP/1.0" 200 - 9 0.002 0.005
```

Below is the Python version:

```
python3 --version
Python 3.8.10

/usr/bin/pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

Below is my nginx configuration post suggestion of odoo documentation:

```
#odoo server
upstream odoo {
  server 127.0.0.1:8069;
}
upstream odoochat {
  server 127.0.0.1:8072;
}

# http -> https
server {
  listen 80;

          root /data/www/html/apps/vidad/ui/vidavitamins_ui/build;

  server_name vidatest.xyz;
  rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;

          root /data/www/html/apps/vidad/ui/vidavitamins_ui/build;

  server_name vidatest.xyz;
  proxy_read_timeout 720s;
  proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
  proxy_send_timeout 720s;

  # Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

  # SSL parameters
  ssl_certificate /etc/certs/certs_14March2022/98fa7f5df02b430e.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/certs/generated-private-key.key;
  ssl_session_timeout 30m;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

  # log
  access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;

  # Redirect longpoll requests to odoo longpolling port
  location /longpolling {
    proxy_pass http://odoochat;
  }

  # Redirect requests to odoo backend server
  location /web {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://odoo;
  }

  location /api/api/ {
     proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8888/api/;
   }

  location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
   }

  # common gzip
  gzip_types text/css text/scss text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
  gzip on;
}
```

Here is the details browser console output in debug mode:

```
POST https://vidatest.xyz/mail/init_messaging 405 (Not Allowed)
POST https://vidatest.xyz/longpolling/poll 405 (Not Allowed)
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (web.assets_backend.min.js:585:55)
(anonymous) @ web.assets_backend.min.js:585
load (async)
(anonymous) @ web.assets_backend.min.js:583
jsonrpc @ web.assets_backend.min.js:582
rpc @ web.assets_backend.min.js:590
(anonymous) @ web.assets_backend.min.js:3324
legacyEnv.session.rpc @ web.assets_backend.min.js:3323
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.min.js:5057
rpc @ web.assets_common.min.js:5057
_trigger_up @ web.assets_backend.min.js:5924
trigger_up @ web.assets_common.min.js:4855
call @ web.assets_common.min.js:4908
_rpc @ web.assets_common.min.js:4908
_makePoll @ web.assets_backend.min.js:5914
_poll @ web.assets_backend.min.js:5914
startPolling @ web.assets_backend.min.js:5913
startPolling @ web.assets_backend.min.js:5893
prototype.<computed> @ web.assets_common.min.js:4716
_startElection @ web.assets_backend.min.js:5900
startPolling @ web.assets_backend.min.js:5890
prototype.<computed> @ web.assets_common.min.js:4716
(anonymous) @ web.assets_backend.min.js:5918
trigger @ web.assets_common.min.js:755
mounted @ web.assets_backend.min.js:2450
__callMounted @ web.assets_common.min.js:1308
complete @ web.assets_common.min.js:1230
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.min.js:1198
flush @ web.assets_common.min.js:1197
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.min.js:1202
requestAnimationFrame (async)
scheduleTasks @ web.assets_common.min.js:1202
start @ web.assets_common.min.js:1191
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.min.js:1195
addFiber @ web.assets_common.min.js:1193
mount @ web.assets_common.min.js:1289
mount @ web.assets_common.min.js:1344
startWebClient @ web.assets_backend_prod_only.min.js:6
await in startWebClient (async)
(anonymous) @ web.assets_backend_prod_only.min.js:3
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.min.js:93
processJob @ web.assets_common.min.js:93
odoo.processJobs @ web.assets_common.min.js:101
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.min.js:94
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.min.js:94
processJob @ web.assets_common.min.js:93
odoo.processJobs @ web.assets_common.min.js:101
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.min.js:94
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.min.js:94
processJob @ web.assets_common.min.js:93
odoo.processJobs @ web.assets_common.min.js:101
odoo.define @ web.assets_common.min.js:79
(anonymous) @ web.assets_backend_prod_only.min.js:10
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check the below Odoo deployment sample from [Odoo documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/administration/install/deploy.html#https).

```
#odoo server
upstream odoo {
  server 127.0.0.1:8069;
}
upstream odoochat {
  server 127.0.0.1:8072;
}

# http -> https
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name vidatest.xyz;
  rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name vidatest.xyz;
  proxy_read_timeout 720s;
  proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
  proxy_send_timeout 720s;

  # Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

  # SSL parameters
  ssl_certificate /etc/certs/certs_14March2022/98fa7f5df02b430e.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/certs/generated-private-key.key;
  ssl_session_timeout 30m;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;


  # log
  access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;

  # Redirect longpoll requests to odoo longpolling port
  location /longpolling {
    proxy_pass http://odoochat;
  }

  # Redirect requests to odoo backend server
  location / {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://odoo;
  }

  # common gzip
  gzip_types text/css text/scss text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
  gzip on;
}
```

Comment: I have updated the Original post with  inspect debug in browser

Comment: I think the issue in your nginx configuration file, You need to add the longpolling redirect please check Odoo deployment and nginx config sample [link](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/administration/install/deploy.html#https)

Comment: i update the original post with the changes to nginx conf if you can review it. It still does not work. What I have noted is the `telnet localhost 8072` is not working which suggests there is no chat service running on that port. Can you help configure that ?

Comment: First add ```longpolling_port = 8072``` and ```proxy_mode = True``` to odoo config file. For nginx config try to edit the ones in my answer without adding to it just change the server name and SSL certificate and check if nginx file is correct by running command ```nginx -t``` and then restart the nginx and Odoo service. then try to open Odoo.

Comment: Your suggestion works but i want to map odoo to this URL -> `https://vidatest.xyz/web` and have my application run on `https://vidatest.xyz`. If I change `location / {` to `location /web {` or `location /web/ {` the error starts to show. Can you please suggest?